# action use variable value for parameter name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this Action Method:

```
public IActionResult SearchHeader(string query, string filter)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Search", new { filter = query });
}
```

Except instead of the parameter being passed to the `Search` `action method` being called `filter`, I need it to be called the `value` of  the `filter` variable being passed into the `SearchHeader` `action method`... how do I do it?

For example if the value of `filter` is `Name` and the value of `query` is `Bob` then I want it to route to

```
.../Search/?Name=Bob
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want the string value of `filter` to be used in the route, not the literal value "filter", which your current code does.

To do that, you can use the `RedirectToAction()` overload that takes a `RouteValueDictionary` and fill the dictionary key of `filter` with `query`:

```
var dictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
dictionary[filter] = query;
return RedirectToAction("Search", dictionary);
```